# Elegant way to evaluate json in recursive manner

Tags: python, json, recursion

I have a nested json structure that has to evaluate into output based in operator sign. I wrote a recursive function to complete the task. The solution doesn't look very good to me. Any elegant way to improve this function would be appreciated. The string representation of json below should should yield 11.

```
d = ["+", 1, ["+", 3,["+", 3,4]]]

def eval_arithmetic(exp):
  op = exp[0]
  if op =="+":
     ret = exp[1] + exp[2]
  elif op == "*":
     ret = exp[1] * exp[2]
  elif op == "/":
    ret = exp[1]/exp[2]
  else:
    ret = exp[1] - exp[2]
  return ret

def eval_numberExpression(exp):
    for idx, item in enumerate(exp):
        if isinstance(item, list):
           y =  eval_numberExpression(item)
           exp[idx] = y
        if (idx == len(exp) and
            ( not isinstance(item, list))):
            val = eval_arithmetic(item)
            return val
    return eval_arithmetic(exp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use unpacking with recursion:

```
import operator
d = {'+':operator.add, '*':operator.mul, '-':operator.sub, '/':operator.truediv}
def eval_l(tokens):
   a, b, c = tokens
   return d[a](b, eval_l(c) if isinstance(c, list) else c)

print(eval_l(["+", 1, ["+", 3,["+", 3,4]]]))
```

Output:

```
11
```